# Is a variable defined by concatenated string constants still a constant?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

This is a PEP8 / style question:

```
API_VERSION = 'v2.4'
API_URL = "https://api.somsite.com/" + API_VERSION + "/"
```

Should `API_URL` be fully capitalized as it is the concatenation of constants?
or should it be lowercase `api_url`?

Comment: A "constant" is just a variable that you'll never re-assign, so sure, it can be uppercase if that is what you intend to signal.

Comment: Use the formatting literal in this case, it is way faster as it does not call any operand, but directly creates a literal string from the interpolation: `f"https://api.somsite.com/{API_VERSION}/"`

Comment: @LuizFerraz honestly, performance is a totally irrelevant consideration here, but from a readability perspective, I agree.

Comment: I agree that performance difference is irrelevant for module/class level constants like this. But serves as a hint, the speed difference from the f-string over concatenation is a huge deal for strings that need to be formatted during runtime multiple times.

Comment: That is all of course assuming you're *using* a Python3 with f-strings :-) I love 'em just for the readability, they're reason enough (IMNSHO) to upgrade to 3.6 (I think) if you're not there yet.